# Attr() to replace href value not workign in Safari browser

Tags: javascript, jquery

My code below is designed to append two query string parameters on all the `<a href` tags on my page. The code works fine in Chrome but does not work on Safari. For some reason on Safari browser it is not appending the parameters. Chrome seems to be working fine. Any ideas why Chrome and Safari would have different results with these jQuery functions? From what I have read it may be related to the way I am using `$this` in the `.each` loop.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  // function to get query string for given parameter
  function GetQueryString(field, url) {
    var href = url ? url : window.location.href;
    var reg = new RegExp('[?&]' + field + '=([^&#]*)', 'i');
    var string = reg.exec(href);
    return string ? string[1] : null;
  };
  var aid = GetQueryString('affiliate'); // returns 'chicken'
  var cmp = GetQueryString('campaign'); // returns 'sandwich'
  var href_param;
  $('a').each(function() {
    if ($(this).is('[href*="?"')) {
      href_param = '&';
    } else {
      href_param = '?';
    }
    var $this = $(this);
    $this.attr("href", $this.attr("href") + href_param + "affiliate=" + aid + "&campaign=" + cmp);
  });
});
```

Comment: "My code below is designed to append two query string parameters on all the..." All the what?

Comment: you forgot ]  in ($(this).is('[href*="?"'))   ==> ($(this).is('[href*="?"]'))

Answer (score 0):

For parse Query from Url String, this example code

```
var QueryString = function () {
  // This function is anonymous, is executed immediately and 
  // the return value is assigned to QueryString!
  var query_string = {};
  var query = window.location.search.substring(1);
  var vars = query.split("&");
  for (var i=0;i<vars.length;i++) {
    var pair = vars[i].split("=");
        // If first entry with this name
    if (typeof query_string[pair[0]] === "undefined") {
      query_string[pair[0]] = decodeURIComponent(pair[1]);
        // If second entry with this name
    } else if (typeof query_string[pair[0]] === "string") {
      var arr = [ query_string[pair[0]],decodeURIComponent(pair[1]) ];
      query_string[pair[0]] = arr;
        // If third or later entry with this name
    } else {
      query_string[pair[0]].push(decodeURIComponent(pair[1]));
    }
  } 
  return query_string;
};

var q = [];
$.each(QueryString(), function(k, v){
//delete the key you want with if
   if(k != "affiliate"){
     q.push( k +"="+ v );
   }
});

// add or modify your query
q.push( "affiliate="+ YOUR_VALUE );
q.push( "campaign="+ YOUR_VALUE );

// finaly
var newPath = document.location.origin +"?"+ q.join("&");
```

This script might be able to help you